# custom page not showing up in template filed

Tags: php, wordpress

I've duplicated a template file in the directory of page template. But nothing show up? I wonder.. I also tried putting test.php in the upper directory (wp-content/themes/twentywelve)

[image]

Comment: You need to change the description in the comments at the top of the template: `/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/`

Comment: Remove the test.php from the patent directory too! If you are extending or modifying a parent theme by using a child theme You need to put all your custom code and files in your child theme folder. Upgrading a parent theme will overwrite and erase any custom files or modifications you've put in the previous folder. A child theme will keep your customisations safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the template file in a text editor.  You should see something like this near the top of the file:

```
/*
 * Template Name: Portfolio
 */
```

(Of course yours will like say something other than *Portfolio*)

This is where WordPress gets the name of the template, for the drop-down when editing pages.

If this is missing, or if they are the same, that will cause problems.

So, either add or edit the `Template Name` comment, so that it is different:

```
/*
 * Template Name: My Template Name
 */
```